# Axis aligned torus collision detection

Tags: collision-detection

I am looking to detect the collision (test for intersection) of axis aligned torus and other axis aligned shapes:

1. Torus and box.
2. Torus and cylinder.
3. Torus and another torus.

There exist algorithms to calculate this for other simple objects (sphere, cylinder, box), however I cannot find the way to do this with torus.

If such algorithm (test) exists, or the only possibility is to approximate torus with some other shapes?